# Avoiding XSS Vulnerability with single quotes, but allow users to use them in input?

Tags: javascript, json, xss

This may be a more basic question, but I am accessing a JSON string from my controller, which accesses the database, on my JavaScript page. I do {!JSENCODE(jsonString)} to be wary of XSS vulnerability with this as users get to specify a name for the objects in the JSON.

The issue is... when doing JSENCODE, it escapes single quotes. Then if I try to JSON.parse() it, the \' throws an error as an invalid character. Replacing \' with \' prevents errors, but then it shows up as \' in the list of object names instead of the single quote (used for apostrophes).

What would be the best course of action to allow users to use single quotes in the names of these objects while avoiding XSS vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are taking data, converting it to JSON, then injecting it into a string literal in a `<script>` element, and then trying to parse the resulting string as JSON.

The problem is that **special characters in JSON are also special characters in JavaScript**.

The good news is that JSON is a subset of JavaScript, so you can just use it as if it were a JavaScript literal.

```
<script>
    var data =  {!JSENCODE(jsonString)};
    console.log(data);
</script>
```

Comment: Well, jsonString is a JSON serialized list from my controller, so it is a string that needs parsed in my javascript. Just doing the {!JSENCODE(jsonString)} will just get me the string.

Comment: @TylerDahle — Then don't double encode it. Just use it.

Comment: A security check pointed it out as an XSS Vulnerability, but I am thinking... if any single quotes are wrapped up in double quotes, are they actually a vulnerability? Because if not, then there wouldn't be a need for the JSENCODE I suppose.